# Set chrome to ignore hosts file

Tags: google-chrome

How can I set chrome to ignore hosts file?

Here is the scenarion:
I have www.example.com site which is Live and customers are using it and now I have got the code hosted on a new server with a host file entry to that server for my domain I am able to browse to the new server. Problem is everytime I want to check whats on live I have to edit my host file entry. So is there an option to manually set one of my browsers ex: Chrome to ignore the host file entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight forward solution. The sort of temporary solution is Browser loads host file only when its loaded so I ended up editing the hostfile entry open the browser instance and changed the host file entry back.
So that way the new browser opened will have a new host file entry loaded.

Comment: I used to rely on this method but Chrome can now dynamically load the hosts file and will adapt to changes made without needing to be restarted. Helpful in most cases, but not here where we want Chrome to ignore the hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

[HostAdminApp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hostadmin-app/mfoaclfeiefiehgaojbmncmefhdnikeg), a Chrome extension, does exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Gaia that extension was very useful.

Comment: After you get to read its syntax instructions it becomes even more powerful. But I don't think you can use it to have one browser ignore an entry but another browser use that entry, since the extension uses the standard syntax for host file comments.

Comment: As of this writing, this plugin seems to be suffering from a bug that does not allow changes to be saved. From the developer's GitHub page for the plugin, seems some changes Google made broke the app, so there's a new one on the store now: [HostAdmin App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hostadmin-app/mfoaclfeiefiehgaojbmncmefhdnikeg)

Comment: Thanks @GiorgioSintichakis, indeed the original plugin shows "NPAPI plugin is required by this app" and is marked as "NOT COMPATIBLE". I will updated the answer to use the plugin you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can, since the hosts file is an operating system wide setting. It would be easier and better to manage if you change the domain of the test server to www.example.local, so www.example.com will go to the live server.

Edit: Another simple solution would be to use a browser in a virtual machine. It could be worth the effort if you need to do a full testing

Comment: No changing domain is not possible as this is not a test site but a live site. Its just that we are changing host provider so need to test it on our new host provider. May just need to edit the host file.

Comment: @Phani check updated answer: Another simple solution would be to use a browser in a virtual machine. It could be worth the effort if you need to do a full testing

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out you may be able to use an issue with Chrome to accomplish this. I was having trouble getting Chrome to recognize/use my /etc/hosts file to locate locally defined IPs. It was always doing a search on the name rahter than going to the locally defined domain.

I had to comment out these 2 lines to get it to work:

## ::1             localhost

## fe80::1%lo0    localhost

So, I am guessing that if you put them in, Chrome will ignore your hosts file. It seems it is an issue the Chrome has with IPv6, so as long as you only need IPv4 for the things in your hosts file you may be able to use this Chrome bug to accomplish what you want. At least until it gets fixed...

Comment: Looks like Chrome no longer suffers from this bug and happily loads the hosts file even with those entries in it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a solution to the actual problem (force the browser to ignore hosts file), but rather a flexible alternative.

Ok, so what you usually do in your site's configuration is to have a server alias for `www.example.com` and `example.com`. So, then you probably enter in your host file something like this `123.231.123.231 example.com` where that IP is your new server's IP and you access your site via `example.com`. Right ?

Well, here's the catch, if you type `www.example.com` in your browser instead of `example.com` you will still see the old site, even if you have set alias with www in your new server's configuration. I think you can apply the same trick with http and https, but you get the idea.

Hope this helps.